# Creating a public key that can be loaded with Python TLSLite parseAsPublicKey

Tags: python, ssl, pem

I'd like to load a public key from Python's TLSlite Library.

The key can be created any way we like, as long as the format is common - so far I'm using a PEM key created with the openssl commandline tool:

```
   openssl genrsa 2048 > private.pem
```

And then:

```
   openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout > public.pem
```

Here's the results:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCw0zAfn11dltN7b3HL+vDsp+oS
rhwAYPjtpMtsdKp7/i5fCf2oAo2wSBPfjM7q9DAZgPrnlzDYldIZ5MooUL2EJ59c
6TRQN/2pBeE59nzvRif1DSgWgZhK7mvjo4YtLS10eqOxY5A8VVyKmNzQ15ILbYwg
8ZwXoiMJJPECmt0iswIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The key will be loaded with:

```
   from libs.tlslite.utils import keyfactory
   pubkey = open('public.pem').read()
   keyfactory.parsePEMKey(pubkey, private=False)
```

However this fails with a SyntaxError. Stripping newlines, only using the part of the string between the dashes, etc. all fail.

I am quite happy to use a different, common key format, however I require TLSLite or another pure-Python solution to be able to read the file, as I am using Google AppEngine.

Comment: Could you post a bit more of your code? The two lines you posted do not currently appear to be related to one another. Should `pubkey` be used in that `keyfactory.parsePEMKey` call?

Comment: @kwatford - good spot - I've fixed the sample code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You should probably include the `implementations` argument, as in:

`parsePEMKey(key_data, private=False, implementations=['python'])`